Second derivative of NCS with respect to knot y-values?
Let $f(c, \vec{y})$ be a natural cubic spline evaluated at $c$, passing through knot y-values $\vec{y}$. Empirically it seems like $\frac {\partial ^2 f}{\partial \vec{y}^2} = 0$. Is this true, and is there a proof for this? Is it only true for a NCS?
